# change popup to modal window

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have the following line of code which opens a pop up window onclick:

```
<%= link_to 'something', :onclick => "javascript:window.open('/users/#{@status.id}/statuses/into_it','popup','width=285,height=300,top=315,left=200');" %>
```

Instead I would like to open a modal window onclick. And if possible remove the modal window if client clicks outside of the modal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for FancyBox?

[www.fancybox.net](http://www.fancybox.net)